# union not working as expected in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I Have a union query:

```
(SELECT
    to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') as "Yr",
    to_char(createdatutc,'MM') as "Mh",
    count(postid) as Freq
FROM conversations
WHERE type = 'Post'
GROUP BY Yr, Mh
HAVING Yr = '2018')
UNION
(SELECT
    to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') as "Yr",
    to_char(createdatutc,'MM') as "Mh",
    count(postid) as Freq
FROM conversations
WHERE type <> 'Post'
GROUP BY Yr, Mh having Yr = '2018')
ORDER BY  Yr, Mh
```

which is throwing the following error upon executing:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "conversations.createdatutc" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

However, If I run them individually they run properly , here createdatutc is a timestamp field

Comment: I don't buy the claim that they run individually, because the first has an alias `"Yr"`, while the `GROUP BY` clause has `Yr` without double quotes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you can refer to a column name without quotes, so on group by clause you can refer to the alias fields without doble quotes

Comment: Not if it contains upper case characters. My underlying point is that you either made a copy-and-paste error, or the individual queries differ.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you , I was not aware of the upper case scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: I'm surprised the individual queries run. You should not be able to use an alias column name in `HAVING`, because `HAVING` occurs before `SELECT`.

With `UNION` you are removing duplicates. So you count the months were there are exactly the same number of posts as non-posts only half. Is this what you are after? Seems strange.

Anyway, with your query you'll get multiple result rows and you wont be able to tell which are for posts and which are for non-posts.

(And just so you know: if type can be null, that won't be counted in any row, because NULL being unknown is considered neither equal nor unequal to 'Post'.)

Here are two ways to write the query:

### One row per month and type

```
SELECT yr, mh, tp, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(createdatutc, 'YYYY') AS yr,
    TO_CHAR(createdatutc, 'MM') AS mh,
    CASE WHEN type = 'Post' THEN 'Post' ELSE 'other' END AS tp
  FROM conversations
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM createdatutc) = 2018
) yr2018
GROUP BY yr, mh, tp
ORDER BY yr, mh, tp;
```

### One row per month

```
SELECT
  yr, mh,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'Post' THEN 1 END) AS count_posts,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type <> 'Post' THEN 1 END) AS count_nonposts
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(createdatutc, 'YYYY') AS yr,
    TO_CHAR(createdatutc, 'MM') AS mh,
    type
  FROM conversations
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM createdatutc) = 2018
) yr2018
GROUP BY yr, mh
ORDER BY yr, mh;
```

You can do this without subqueries (derived tables), but then you'll have to repeat the same expressions again and again.

Comment: @jarlh: I guess I started earlier ;-) Sometimes I take so long to write my answers that by the time I'm ready, several answers have been posted and one even got accepted.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for detailed answer and explaining the possible scenarios where it might have failed , very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Do the to_char extraction etc in a derived table, `group by` its result:

```
select "Yr", "Mh", count(postid), type
from
(
    SELECT
        to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') as "Yr",
        to_char(createdatutc,'MM') as "Mh",
        postid,
        case when type = 'Post' then 'Post' else 'NotPost' end type
    FROM conversations
) dt
where "Yr" = 2018
group by  "Yr", "Mh", type
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove alias column name from group by like below

```
   select * from (
    (
    Select EXTRACT(Year FROM createdatutc::date) as "Yr",
     EXTRACT(MONTH FROM createdatutc::date) as "Mh",
    count(postid) as Freq 
     from conversations 
    where type = 'Post' 
    group by
     EXTRACT(Year FROM createdatutc::date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM createdatutc::date) 
    having EXTRACT(Year FROM createdatutc::date) = 2018)
     union 
    (Select to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') as "Yr",
     to_char(createdatutc,'MM') as "Mh", count(postid) as Freq 
    from conversations where type <> 'Post' 
    group by EXTRACT(Year FROM createdatutc::date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM createdatutc::date)
 having EXTRACT(Year FROM createdatutc::date) = 2018)
) as t
order by  Yr, Mh
```

Comment: Thank you it removes the error but now group by is considering the day also while grouping by maybe because `createdatutc` is a timestamp. I wanted it to group by month and year only ignoring the day. Also why my earlier query was not working any idea

Comment: @Ibhagawati  what is the data type of this "createdatutc" column

Comment: createdatutc is a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

With help from @zaynul and @Thorsten I modified my query as below

```
select 
  yr,
  mh,
  sum(freq)
from 
(
  (
    Select 
      to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') as "Yr",
      to_char(createdatutc,'MM') as "Mh",
      count(postid) as Freq from conversations where type = 'Post'
    group by 
      to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY'),
      to_char(createdatutc,'MM')
    having to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') = '2018'
  ) 
  union 
  (
    Select
      to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') as "Yr",
      to_char(createdatutc,'MM') as "Mh", 
      count(postid) as Freq 
    from conversations where type <> 'Post'
    group by 
      to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY'), 
      to_char(createdatutc,'MM') 
    having to_char(createdatutc,'YYYY') = '2018'
  )
) as t 
group by yr, Mh 
order by Yr, Mh
```

which did the trick for me , Thank you guys for your help and supportenter code here

Sample data:

```
+ -------+--------------+------+
| postid | createdatutc | type |
+ -------+--------------+------+
|      1 | 2018-01-01   | Post |
|      2 | 2018-01-02   | Nope |
|      3 | 2018-01-03   | Njet |
|      4 | 2018-01-04   | Nada |
|      5 | 2018-02-01   | Post |
|      6 | 2018-02-02   | Post |
|      7 | 2018-02-03   | Post |
|      8 | 2018-02-04   | Nada |
|      9 | 2018-03-01   | Post |
|     10 | 2018-03-02   | Post |
|     11 | 2018-03-03   | Nope |
|     12 | 2018-03-04   | Nada |
+ -------+--------------+------+
```

Result:

```
+ -----+----+-----------+
| yr   | mh | sum(freq) |
+ -----+----+-----------+
| 2018 | 01 |         4 |
| 2018 | 02 |         4 |
| 2018 | 03 |         2 |
+ -----+----+-----------+
```

Comment: If any one answer helps you accept his or her answer , and you can only accept one answer

Comment: Your query looks awfully complicated. All you do is count rows per month, only that for months where there are exactly the same number of posts as non-posts do you count half. Is this *really* what you are after? This seems so strange. (I've updated my answer btw, as I was wrong about `UNION` in your query.)

Comment: I've added sample data to your answer, so as to show what the query does.